# linux mounting issue from windows to Linux

Tags: windows, linux, ubuntu, partitioning

i have an Ubntu machine with 30GB space and need to create a folder in "/" as "/server". I have 50GB space in NTFS(windows) . i want to join this 50GB to linux how can i merge these two.

Answer (score 1):

You wish to mount the NTFS partition to /server?

Assuming your 50GB drive is /dev/sdb1:

`sudo -i` (mounting should be done as root)

`cd /` (you want it in /server)

`mkdir server` (mount points must exist)

`mount /dev/sdb1 -t NTFS /server` (mount...this may error out.)

This will not persist across reboots. You will need to edit `/etc/fstab` to do so. Make a backup of that file before you continue.

Comment: Here's a fstab guide if you need one: http://mesanna.com/2009/02/02/how-to-mount-a-partition-automatically-in-ubuntu-linux/

Answer (score 0):

Both are different file systems. So cant merge it. You can mount windows partitions to linux and by some windows softwares can open linux partitions to windows.

Answer (score 0):

as stated by Kumar P you cannot merge them because those two are on different filesystems:
anyway you could be interested in [LVM](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/) for the next time.

Regards

Comment: "merge" could mean joining two partitions to a single filesystem, as LVM allows, or it could mean making the space available somewhere in the filesystem tree (eg, a simple mount).  it's not clear enough what the OP wants to accomplish to guess.

Comment: I supposed he wants to joint 'em because he tolds "i want to join this 50GB to linux": anyway a little more contributes from the OP are welcome! :D

Answer (score 0):

If you mean by 'merge' to use the harddisk space in Linux, may I suggest something: Reformat the NTFS partition with ext3/4 or any other filesystem of your choice, and mount it in the var folder `/var/server` as server folder. This would have the advantage that no matter how many stuff ends up in your server folder, it will never effect the system.

Answer (score 0):

You should ble able to install ntfs-3g, load the FUSE module to load on boot and basically follow the same steps outlined above but mount with something like

```
mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/YOURDRIVE /your/mount/point
```

Then add something like this to fstab

```
/dev/YOURDRIVE  /your/mount/point         ntfs-3g   silent,umask=0002,utf8=true
```

--

Ubuntu also seems to have a short tutorial and some documentation about settings up NTFS-3g to read/write to NTFS drives.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions/ThirdPartyNTFS3G